# Is a way to subscribe EWS notification like Microsoft Graph API to get the notification

Tags: exchange-server, outlook-addin, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am new to EWS and want to find a way to subscribe EWS notification.

I build an Outlook Add-in and use **Microsoft Graph API** to subscribe and handle notifications for Microsoft 365 if the customer's calendar has some changes from [Microsoft Graph REST APIs for mail, calendars, and contacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/office-365-rest-apis-for-mail-calendars-and-contacts). But Exchange server doesn't support graph API.

Also, i read some Microsoft Documents, like [Notification subscriptions, mailbox events, and EWS in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/notification-subscriptions-mailbox-events-and-ews-in-exchange). It menstions **Streaming notifications**. The workflow is from [Service callback tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/mail-apps-for-outlook-and-ews-in-exchange). It's not very good as Graph API which will send the notification automatically.

So, i want to ask whether Microsoft has similar solution for Add-in on Exchange or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is all over the place.

If you’re creating a new application at this moment I would suggest to leave EWS for what it is, and focus on Graph. My guess is that EWS won’t be around for long anymore. An other reason to use EWS is if you want to connect to on-premise Exchange servers.

Graph has support for notifications, but it’s not a connection that stays open. It works by registering a public available “callback” to which updates will be posted.